# What kind of green apple is this, and is it safe to eat it?

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits, apples

[image][image]

Can anyone tell me what kind of apple tree this is and if it’s safe to eat the apples?
It’s a shame to see these go to waste but I’m afraid to eat them without knowing.

Comment: I would cut off the brownish patch of skin from the left one and otherwise not hesitate making use of them.

Comment: if they are in fact apples, they can be eaten.

Comment: Depending on location and type of apple ;they tend to ripen in late Sept, and Oct.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure those can be eaten (at ones own responsibility, of course: no medical advice here :-)

Among apples I know, yours to me look a bit similar to [Transparent White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Transparent). Personally, I would cut off the brownish patch of skin from the left one and otherwise not hesitate making use of them in due time. (I'd prefer apple pie or apple juice.) Notice e.g. [this site](http://www.davewilson.com/product-information/product/apples) (from a nursery in California), which describes multiple varieties of apples e.g. with "brown russet skin", but apparently delicious nevertheless.

Comment: They do look very similar to the Transparent White. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @LSNorCal Your're welcome! Welcome to the site (and don't forget to also "accept" the answer that satisfies your needs).

Comment: *Might* be a bit small, unripe yet. Be prepared for *sour*.